# static function output varies from ordinary fn output

Tags: c++, static-members

When I use a

```
static int CompareFunction(const void* _g1, const void* _g2);
```

the input to qsort is right

but using

```
int CompareFunction(const void* _g1, const void* _g2);
```

the input to qsort is wrong. and the error is : 
`error: argument of type 'int (<namespace>::<ClassName>::)(const void*, const void*)' does not match '__compar_fn_t {aka int (*)(const void*, const void*)}'`

How can static change the behavior in such a way ? I mean the all I am doing is just changing a function in a class to be static which means it now lacks this pointer. There is no more change I am making.

Comment: If your comparator needs access to parts of your class, try `std::sort` instead of `qsort`. This will give you a lot more flexibility as you can use a functor or lambda function instead of just a plain function with no additional arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-static function can only be called on an instance of an object. There is no instance of an object to call the function on inside `qsort` (it just has pointers that it considers opaque), so it cannot invoke a member function.

Answer (score 1):

A static member function is a regular function, but a non-static member function is something different.  The need to have the extra hidden "this" parameter is what makes the difference.